# Symfony rest api

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a rest api application with symfony in backend.
My problem is that when I try to lauch a GET request, the application runs without giving any response even after even after some ten minutes.

this is the request method:

```
/**
 * CounterRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class CounterRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $date
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getValuesByNameAndDate(string $name, int $date)
    {
        $query = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->leftJoin('c.values', 'v', 'WITH')
            ->addSelect('v')
            ->where('c.name = :name')
            ->andWhere('v.date = :date')
            ->setParameters(
                array(
                    'date' => $date,
                    'name' => $name
                )
            )
            ->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
    }

}
```

The CounterValue Entity:

```
/**
 * CounterValue
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="counter_value")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CounterValueRepository")
 */
class CounterValue
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="float")
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="integer")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var Counter
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Counter", inversedBy="values")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     */
    private $counter;

    /**
     * @var City
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="values"))
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     */
    protected $city;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime('-1 day');
        $this->date = strtotime($date->format('d-m-Y'));
    }

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set value.
     *
     * @param float $value
     *
     * @return CounterValue
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * Set date.
     *
     * @param int $date
     *
     * @return CounterValue
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * @return Counter
     */
    public function getCounter(): Counter
    {
        return $this->counter;
    }

    /**
     * @param Counter $counter
     */
    public function setCounter(Counter $counter): void
    {
        $this->counter = $counter;
    }

    /**
     * @return City
     */
    public function getCity(): City
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @param City $city
     */
    public function setCity(City $city): void
    {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

}

/**
 * Counter
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="counter")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CounterRepository")
 */
class Counter
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var XmlFile
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="XmlFile", inversedBy="counters", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $xmlFile;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CounterValue", mappedBy="counter", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $values;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->values = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Counter
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set xmlFile
     *
     * @param XmlFile $xmlFile
     */
    public function setXmlFile(XmlFile $xmlFile)
    {
        $this->xmlFile = $xmlFile;
    }

    /**
     * Get xmlFile
     *
     * @return XmlFile
     */
    public function getXmlFile(): XmlFile
    {
        return $this->xmlFile;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getValues(): ArrayCollection
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $values
     */
    public function setValues(ArrayCollection $values): void
    {
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    /**
     * Add $value
     *
     * @param CounterValue $value
     */
    public function addValue(CounterValue $value)
    {
        $value->setCounter($this);
        if(!$this->values->contains($value)){
            $this->values->add($value);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally my method in controller

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$counterRep = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Counter');
return $counterRep->getValuesByNameAndDate('L.IRATHO.E2G.CSFB.ExecSuccOut', 1533600000);
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the place in your code where the application stalls? Do you see anything in `var/logs/*.log`? Do you have a very large database?

Answer (score 0):

Just return a Json response like this.

```
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $counterRep = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Counter')->getValuesByNameAndDate('L.IRATHO.E2G.CSFB.ExecSuccOut', 1533600000);
        return new JsonResponse(['success' => true, 'code' => Response::HTTP_OK, 'data' => $counterRep]);
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['success' => false,'code' => $exception->getCode() ,'message' => $exception->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller action should return instance of

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
```

You try to return result of query builder `$query->getResult()`

You need to change it to something like

```
public function counterValuesAction(Request $request) {
    try {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $counterRep = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Counter');
        $values = $counterRep->getValuesByNameAndDate('L.IRATHO.E2G.CSFB.ExecSuccOut', 1533600000);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return new Response($values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Symfony 4+:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class CounterController extends AbstractController
{
    public function listAction(
        CounterRepository $repository // DI works like this in Controllers...
    ) {
        $result = $repository->getValuesByNameAndDate('L.IRATHO.E2G.CSFB.ExecSuccOut', 1533600000);
        // use JsonResponse object to create JSON response
        return $this->json($result, Response::HTTP_OK); 
    }
}
```

```
// routes.yaml
counter_list:
  path: /counter
  controller: App\Controller\CounterController::listAction
  methods: GET
```

Clear cache and try to send GET request to http://your-dev-host/counter

**How does it work?**

**Controller**

You need to create controller *CounterController* class with action function *listAction*. It is good practice to add *Action* postfix to action function.

You can define services or other DI objects as parameters in action functions. DI will set it. For example:

```
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function listAction(
        Request $request,
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        ValidatorInterface $validator,
        CounterRepository $repository
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In order to send good response with JSON and all headers that is needed you need to use AbstractController::json function. It creates JsonResponse object. You can check it implementation.

More information about symfony controllers you can find in this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

**Routing**

Next step is to create route for your new controller action. You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Adding record to config/routes.yaml file as i did
2. Use annotations (Annotations is bad practice because comments should not break programm)

More information about routing you can find in this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

**It does not work for me! How can I debug it?**

First, dont panic and read error message. Also, you can check if routing works well. You can do it using command

```
$ bin/console debug:router
 ----------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------- 
  Name                    Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                 
 ----------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------- 
  _preview_error          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}             
  register_token          POST     ANY      ANY    /auth/register                       
  refresh_token           POST     ANY      ANY    /auth/refresh                        
  auth_login              POST     ANY      ANY    /auth/login                          
  restroom_list           GET      ANY      ANY    /api/v1/restroom                      
 ----------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------
```

In table you need to check your new url and how Symfony sees it.

Second, try to send request to this URL using curl and check response.

```
$ curl http://localhost/auth/login
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: Are you serious? Stackoverflow is dead man :)... this question is already outdated